# Returning list of projects that are assigned to a person

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, partial

I’m creating a project management template and I’ve bumped into problem.

I need to return a list of projects to 1 cell assigned to a certain member in a given time period (*does project falls in a period or not*).

When retrieving project names that are assigned to certain person in a period there is a problem because the range of cells that contains information of enrolled members includes several codes in text form - XX, YZ etc. `F:F`. Cells that include information about code assembled from 3 columns(*based on the type of engagement*) that could contain same person several times, cells that in that 3 columns also could contain several codes.

Ive managed to make a formula that retrieves list of projects based on starting date `H:H`, and deadline `I:I` in 1 cell:

[image]

No luck though with implementing binding to certain members. I’ve tried using another `IF` cycle:

`{=TEXTJOIN(“; “;TRUE;IF($H$3:$H$13<=D$19;IF($I$3:$I$13>=C$19;IF($F3:$F$13=“*XX*”;$A$3:$A$13;””);””);””))}`

Result - empty cell

I’ve tried implementing `VLOOKUP` and `COUNTIF` but so far unsuccessfully

I would really appreciate any possible solutions or workarounds, thanks

Comment: Screenshots would probably help.

Comment: So you need to know what projects a given member in a given date is partecipating in?

Comment: @pgSystemTester Sorry for the wait, I’ve added an example

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Yes, that is my goal

Comment: PNG attachments are visually useful, but cannot be used to replicate the problem.  Please attach CSV exports of each of the sheets, so that the data can be loaded in my test bed.

Comment: @donPablo 
Oh, okay, but hot do I exactly do that? Aren't formulas getting erased during CSV export?

Comment: I don't have the TEXTJOIN function, so i can't really test it. Can you try `=TEXTJOIN("; ";TRUE;IFERROR(LEFT(FIND($B20,$G$3:$G$11),0)&(1/(C$19>=$H$3:$H$11)*1/(C$19<=$I$3:$I$11)),""))`

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Thank you! Your idea was a great help! Your formula returned 1, if project included certain person, so I've added up 1 more `IF` cycle and it worked! Great thanks!

My final formula looks like this 
`{=TEXTJOIN("; ";TRUE;IFERROR(LEFT(FIND($B21;$G$3:$G$13);0)&IF((1/(C$19>=$H$3:$H$13)*1/(D$19<=$I$3:$I$13))=1;$A$3:$A$13;"");""))}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a [filter function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function) to get this. I used an example on [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n2sde3GDOiWDYBcEcGNuREMGabGtK8ADlP0s3AZKonY/edit), but it should work exactly the same in Excel. Basically you want to textjoin an array which you filter by meeting multiple and statements (*) along with one OR condition (shown with pluses) over four columns.
Double check the columns and ranges, but I think this works.

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTER($A$3:$A$19,
    ($H$3:$H$19<=$D$19) * ($I$3:$I$19>=$C$19) * ( 
       (isnumber(find($B20,$D$3:$D$19))+
       (isnumber(find($B20,$E$3:$E$19)))+ 
       (isnumber(find($B20,$F$3:$F$19)))+
       (isnumber(find($B20,$G$3:$G$19))) ))))
```